# How to load a local picture in three20's Photo Browser

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, three20

in three20's TTCatalog demo, PhotoTest1Controller.m .there's some code

```
[[[MockPhoto alloc]
initWithURL:@"http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/bmiddle/6e8f23a5jw1dk7pylzs8ij.jpg"
smallURL:@"http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/thumbnail/6e8f23a5jw1dk7pylzs8ij.jpg"
size:CGSizeMake(320, 480)] autorelease],
```

can i replace these URLs with local path.
i put the pictures into app's bundle.

Answer (score 0):

File URLs (`file://`) should work just fine. For images in your app bundle you can use `-[NSBundle URLForResource:withExtension:]`:

```
NSURL *imageURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"foo" withExtension:@"jpg"];
```

On iOS < 4.0 you must combine path-based `NSBundle` methods with `+[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`:

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"jpg"];
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath];
```